# how to get the current balance of each source and then get the percentage of it from the total sum of all sources

Tags: mysql

SELECT source, SUM(deposit), SUM(distribute), SUM(deposit)-SUM(distribute),(SUM(deposit)-SUM(distribute)) / (SUM(SUM(deposit)-SUM(distribute)) * 100 as percentage
FROM tbl_sourceofFunds
GROUP BY source

it keep saying "#1111 - Invalid use of group function"

```
source |    deposit    |    withdraw | 
--------------------------------------
A      |    300,000.00 |             |
B      |    300,000.00 |             |
C      |    220,000.00 |             |
A      |               |   53,300.00 |
A      |     20,000.00 |             |
B      |               |    3,700.00 |
C      |               |    5,100.00 |
```

what I meant is to get:

```
source | sum.deposit   |sum.withdraw |   balance   | percentage  |
------------------------------------------------------------------
A      |    320,000.00 |      53,300 |  266,700.00 |  34.284612  |
B      |    300,000.00 |       3,700 |  296,300.00 |  38.089729  |
C      |    220,000.00 |       5,100 |  214,900.00 |  34.284612  |
```

Comment: Why doesn't your query work?

Comment: yes it does because i put the sum of all sources. my problem is how to multiply the

Comment: shouldn't you get sum(deposit) for A as 340000 instead of 320000

Comment: oh yes its 320000, sorry

Comment: The sum of deposit - distribute is 797900 not 777900.

Comment: my bad, please see the edited table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include a calculation to get the total across the entire table by including it in a sub query

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sourcefunds;
CREATE TABLE sourcefunds(source VARCHAR(1),    deposit    DECImal (10,2),    distribute decimal(10,2)); 
insert into sourcefunds values
('A'  ,        320000.00 ,  null           ),
('B'  ,        300000.00 ,  null           ),
('C'  ,        220000.00 ,  null           ),
('A'  ,             null  ,   53300.00 ),
('A'  ,         20000.00 ,  null           ),
('B'  ,             null  ,    3700.00 ),
('C'  ,             null  ,    5100.00 );

SELECT source, SUM(deposit), SUM(distribute), SUM(deposit)-SUM(distribute),
    (SUM(deposit)-SUM(distribute)) / (select sum(deposit) - sum(distribute) from sourcefunds) * 100 as percentage
        FROM sourcefunds
        GROUP BY source;

+--------+--------------+-----------------+------------------------------+------------+
| source | SUM(deposit) | SUM(distribute) | SUM(deposit)-SUM(distribute) | percentage |
+--------+--------------+-----------------+------------------------------+------------+
| A      |    340000.00 |        53300.00 |                    286700.00 |  35.931821 |
| B      |    300000.00 |         3700.00 |                    296300.00 |  37.134979 |
| C      |    220000.00 |         5100.00 |                    214900.00 |  26.933200 |
+--------+--------------+-----------------+------------------------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And if you want grand total use rollup

```
SELECT source, SUM(deposit), SUM(distribute), SUM(deposit)-SUM(distribute),
    (SUM(deposit)-SUM(distribute)) / (select sum(deposit) - sum(distribute) from sourcefunds) * 100 as percentage
        FROM sourcefunds
        GROUP BY source with rollup;

+--------+--------------+-----------------+------------------------------+------------+
| source | SUM(deposit) | SUM(distribute) | SUM(deposit)-SUM(distribute) | percentage |
+--------+--------------+-----------------+------------------------------+------------+
| A      |    340000.00 |        53300.00 |                    286700.00 |  35.931821 |
| B      |    300000.00 |         3700.00 |                    296300.00 |  37.134979 |
| C      |    220000.00 |         5100.00 |                    214900.00 |  26.933200 |
| NULL   |    860000.00 |        62100.00 |                    797900.00 | 100.000000 |
+--------+--------------+-----------------+------------------------------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select source, deposit, withdrew, 
    deposit - distribute as balance, 
    (deposit - distribute) / (Select sum(deposit - distribute) from tbl_sourceofFunds) * 100 as percentage
From (
SELECT source, 
        SUM(deposit) as deposit, 
        SUM(distribute) as withdrew
FROM tbl_sourceofFunds 
GROUP BY source
) x
```

Comment: This will fail because there is no column called deposit returned from the sub query x , When correcting for this  the percentage calculated is null.

Comment: SELECT source, 
        SUM(deposit) as "deposit", 
        SUM(distribute) as withdrew
FROM tbl_sourceofFunds 
GROUP BY source
"deposit" there

Comment: rather than discuss this why don't you just run it?